# Is it possible to detect/scan for Samsung Galaxy Watch using BLE in react native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, apple-watch, samsung-galaxy-gear, react-native-ble-plx

I'm working with [this](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) library in achieving two features in my react native app for iOS and Andriod

Feature

1. I was trying to find/scan Samsung Galaxy Watch and Apple Watch using react-native-ble-plx library in react native. I was able to detect other nearby BLE Peripheral devices using my react native app, but unable to discover Apple Watch and Samsung Galaxy watch. Is it possible to scan Samsung Galaxy watches and Apple Watches via react native app using ble?
2. I'm also working on other solution by developing a Tizen Watch App which will be installed in Galaxy watch and start sending some values from watch using the BLE GATT profile in Tizen with custom service and characteristics UUID's. Is it possible to Connect to Samsung watch without knowing its UUID via react-native-ble-plx library in react native?

I was able to detect my Apple Watch with some Apps named BLE Scanner , nRF Connect but not from my react native app using react-native-ble-plx library. What might be the reason?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: Updated With Scanning Code:

```
 scanAndConnect() {
   console.log('Scanning Started');
   this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
     if (error) {
       Alert.alert(i18next.t('ble_alert_title'), error.message);
       return;
      }
     console.log(
       'Detected Device Details:',
       device?.id,
       device?.name,
       device?.localName,
  );
 }
```

Comment: This is weird... Could you share your code with us? At least the scanning part would be nice

Comment: @M.Kotzjan i have added the scanning part code. Which part you felt weird?

Comment: That you found the devices using nRF Connect but not with your app. But you said that you found other BLE devices?